# Can someone else register the same program and use their own Youtube API key instead of mine?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I am working on a program that queries the Youtube API and I have my own API key. My friends were interested in using this as well and I was wondering if it was allowed/possible for them to register the same program and get their own key, then I can insert their key into the Youtube API call instead of using mine for each instance? I just want to make sure I'm following all the rules to not get my API key banned or the program. Thanks!